# Problem when adding teardrops in Altium

Tags: pcb, altium

It seems easy to add teardrops for connections in Altium. But in my design, after adding teardrops, it throwing errors which indicating the 'teardrops' violate my clearance constraint such as:

> Clearance Constraint: (0.144mm < 0.2mm) Between Pad
>   U16-A13(65mm,52.6mm) on L1 And Region (0 hole(s)) L1

[image]

Won't Altium resize the teardrop size according to the clearance rules? How to solve this problem?

Comment: Screenshot of the area of the violation? Issue could be that polygons can be repoured but regions can't.

Answer (score 4):

In your Teardrop options window, make sure the "Adjust teardrop size" checkbox is checked and that "Force teardrops" is unchecked. If you have "Force teardrops" checked then it will create the teardrop regions regardless of what's around it, and will ignore the clearance rules.

[image]

And, as Koray mentioned, if you have a polygon pour around the teardrop you will need to repour, and if you have a region around the teardrop you will need to manually modify it to meet clearance rules.

Comment: I confirm that I've checked it, that's what confused me.

Comment: It seems it failed to adjust the size.

Comment: It can only adjust it so much, especially when your clearance is all the way up at 0.2 mm with such large pads. You might want to try shrinking your pads a bit.

Comment: It's vias under BGA chip, and is already made as smaller as possible, so shrink the pad may not a good idea.

Comment: In that case, if you're doing a BGA, you need to find a board manufacturer who can handle tighter clearances than 0.2 mm. You will probably need to find a supplier who can do 0.1 mm.

Answer (score 1):

Probably  firstly, you are adding a region
secondly you are adding teardrops. 
You need to re-modify your regions after teardrops.

If you use polygon instead of region, you can do this modification automaticaly. just repour polygon will solve.

Answer (score 1):

I had the some problem but now, I found the reason.
You have to enable the "Online DRC" ( Preferences -> PCB Editor)

[image]

Only with this option, it considers your Design-Rules.